# How do I solve $\frac{d}{dt} \ln{\left( W(t) \right)} = k W(t)^\alpha$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the equation $$\frac{d}{dt} \ln{\left( W(t) \right)} = k W(t)^\alpha$$

Where $\alpha < 0,$ $k > 0$ and $W(0) = W_0 > 0$

By chain rule I think this is equivalent to $$\frac{W'}{W} = k W^\alpha$$ So the (non-linear?) ODE I am trying to solve is $$W' = kW^{\alpha+1}$$

If $\alpha = -1$ then $W(t) = kt$ but then $W_0 = 0 \not > 0$ so the trivial case is of no interest. How do I solve an equation like this? Excuse the inconsistency in notation

Comment: $$(W^{-\alpha})'=-\alpha W^{-\alpha-1}W'=-\alpha k\implies W^{-\alpha}(t)=W^{-\alpha}(0)-k\alpha t$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a separable ODE. Since:
$$\frac{W'}{W^{\alpha+1}}=k, \tag{1}$$
assuming $\alpha\neq 0$ we have:
$$ -\left.\frac{1}{W^\alpha}\right|_{0}^{t} = \alpha kt\tag{2}$$
hence:
$$ W(t)=\left(\frac{1}{W_0^\alpha}-\alpha kt\right)^{-1/\alpha}.\tag{3}$$

Comment: Sorry I'm rusty with my differential equations. Seperable means you can put it into a form where you integrate both sides right? I am a little unsure how you got from step 1 to step 2? Also the notation you use for step two I would interpret to evaluate to $\frac{-1}{W^t} - \frac{-1}{W^0}$ ?

Comment: @HBeel: yes to everything. To go from $(1)$ to $(2)$ it is enough to integrate both terms between $0$ and $t$.

Comment: From $(1)$ to $(2)$ have you integrated both sides, and also multiplied by $\alpha$?

Comment: @HBeel: yes, exactly.

Comment: Yes I get it now, thanks Jack

Comment: @HBeel: you're welcome.